# cppcheck: error: unrecognized command line option: "--file-filter

Tags: c, cppcheck

I am developing `C` code on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

By running `cppcheck -q --project=build/proj1/compile_commands.json --file-filter='src/base/Myfile.c'`

I got the error

```
cppcheck: error: unrecognized command line option: "--file-filter=src/base/Myfile.c".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version of `cppcheck` included in Ubuntu 20.04 is not the latest:

```
$ apt show cppcheck | grep Version
Version: 1.90-4build1
```

cppcheck 1.90 was released in 2019. The `--file-filter` argument was introduced in commit [fcd5cda97](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/commit/fcd5cda97) in 2020:

```
$ git show fcd5cda97f10085c7def7fda6fc6199f624010ce
commit fcd5cda97f10085c7def7fda6fc6199f624010ce
Author: fuzzelhjb <chschmidt9@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jan 10 08:57:37 2020 +0100

    Check selected files from project (#2378)

diff --git a/cli/cmdlineparser.cpp b/cli/cmdlineparser.cpp
index 3fbc7f6c6..292327051 100644
--- a/cli/cmdlineparser.cpp
+++ b/cli/cmdlineparser.cpp
@@ -376,6 +376,10 @@ bool CmdLineParser::parseFromArgs(int argc, const char* const argv[])
                 mSettings->xml = true;
             }

+            // use a file filter
+            else if (std::strncmp(argv[i], "--file-filter=", 14) == 0)
+                mSettings->fileFilter = std::string(argv[i] + 14);
+
             // Only print something when there are errors
             else if (std::strcmp(argv[i], "-q") == 0 || std::strcmp(argv[i], "--quiet") == 0)
                 mSettings->quiet = true;
@@ -1035,6 +1039,9 @@ void CmdLineParser::printHelp()
               "    --exitcode-suppressions=<file>\n"
               "                         Used when certain messages should be displayed but\n"
               "                         should not cause a non-zero exitcode.\n"
+              "    --file-filter=<str>  Analyze only those files matching the given filter str\n"
+              "                         Example: --file-filter=*bar.cpp analyzes only files\n"
+              "                                  that end with bar.cpp.\n"
               "    --file-list=<file>   Specify the files to check in a text file. Add one\n"
               "                         filename per line. When file is '-,' the file list will\n"
               "                         be read from standard input.\n"
```

The current release version of cppcheck appears to be 2.7.